# Cron ignoring PHP commands

Tags: php, cron, debian

I have a crontab which looks like this (can be in any order - and the scripts could be anything) :

```
*/30 * * * * python /full/path/script.py > /full/path/log.log 2>&1
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /full/path/script.php > /full/path/log.log 2>&
```

The Python command will work just fine, but the PHP one won't.

**What I did :**

- I use the fullpath to the binary in the cron command
- I added the full path to the binary in the header of the PHP script :

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/php
  <?php
  ```
- I have double checked all paths (binary, script)
- I have double checked PHP cli version
- I have double checked that PHP cli is working correctly (I can run the script from the shell)
- I have enabled the logging and displaying of all PHP errors in the PHP cli .ini file
- I have checked the permissions of the script
- I have made the script executable
- I have tried running dummy scripts (just echo something, or write a file)
- I have rebooted cron
- I have double checked the log file (works with the Python command, not with the PHP one)

**What is happening :**

Absolutely nothing ! No matter what PHP command(s) I have in that file, nothing happens at all. The log while stays empty, nothing is ever ran.

I have been searching a long time before posting this, others had similar issue but most of the time it was just a path and / or permission issue. I don't think it's the case here.

The fact that nothing happens at all is driving me crazy. Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be helpful but one obvious difference is that in the crontab entry for the php script you have `2>&` and not `2>&1`. I'm really not sure what exactly difference does this make but it's there.

Comment: @mrun Freaking hell... It was just a stupid syntax error... I have just wasted hours on this. I was so deep into it that I didn't even notice this. Thank you :)

Comment: yep, we've all been there :) I'm glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a syntax error, as pointed out by mrun in a comment :

```
2>& instead of 2>&1
```

Stupid really, but solved !